# Click a button on floating window using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm having issues getting an AppleScript to run for an app called AutoRate. The script below was originally made for version 1.5.5. I've already tried to mess with AppleScript to get it to run on 1.6, but because I've never really used AppleScript before I'm not getting anywhere. The picture shows 1.6 on top and 1.5.5 on the bottom. The 2nd photo shows the hierarchy for 1.6. Any help is appreciated.

```
tell application "AutoRate"
    activate
    -- Hide app
     tell application "System Events" to key code 4 using {command down}
    -- Press 'begin rating'
     tell button "Begin" of window 2 "main" to perform action
    -- Try to quit afterwards
     quit
end tell
```

[image: AutoRate 1.5.5 on top. AutoRate 1.6 on bottom]

[image: Accessibility Inspector]

Comment: If anyone wants to mess with the actual app and scripts: https://code.google.com/archive/p/autorate/downloads

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this on version 1.6. This code is for clicking the button "Begin Rating"

```
tell application "AutoRate"
    activate
end tell
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    click button "Begin Rating" of window "AutoRate" of application process "AutoRate"
end tell
```

And this code is for clicking the button "Revert Ratings"

```
tell application "AutoRate"
    activate
end tell
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    click button "Revert Ratings" of window "AutoRate" of application process "AutoRate"
end tell
```